# Truncating Trials

Tags: awk

I am in need of some assistance. I have a data file (pilot subject) with three trials, each with around 1500 data points. Each trial needs to be truncated to 1500 data points. I am including the code I have been using as well as a sample of the data file below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    `BEGIN{ SKIP=0}
{ 
if ( $1=="MSG" && SKIP==0 )
{
    FS=" "
    printf("\n%s",$6)
    SKIP=1;
}
else if ( $1=="MSG" && SKIP==1 )
{
    FS=" "
    printf(" %d",$6)
    SKIP=0;
}
else

    FS="\t"
    printf(" %.2f",($3+$4)/2)

}
}


`MSG    1   # Message: bince.bmp                
 MSG    1   # Message: 103              
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   0   0   0   0   0
 SMP    1   10.44   10.44   11.26   11.26   0
 SMP    1   10.19   10.19   11.03   11.03   0
 SMP    1   10.09   10.09   11.23   11.23   0
 SMP    1   10.24   10.24   11.03   11.03   0
 SMP    1   10.09   10.09   11.3    11.3    0
 SMP    1   10.27   10.27   11.16   11.16   0
 SMP    1   10.02   10.02   11.22   11.22   0
 SMP    1   10.01   10.01   11.16   11.16   0
 SMP    1   10.28   10.28   11.16   11.16   0
 SMP    1   10.22   10.22   11.3    11.3    0
 SMP    1   10.18   10.18   11.25   11.25   0
 SMP    1   10.37   10.37   11.26   11.26   0
 SMP    1   10.54   10.54   11.22   11.22   0
 SMP    1   10.19   10.19   11.26   11.26   0
 SMP    1   10.39   10.39   11.27   11.27   0
```

The output should end up looking like this, with each trial being one row with a designated number of samples:

```
' 101 0.00 0.00 0.00...10.23 10.23 12.12 12.12 
  103 0.00 0.00 0.00...10.23 10.23 12.12 12.12 
  104 0.00 0.00 0.00...10.23 10.23 12.12 12.12'
```

Adding something like this just truncates 1500 samples, not within each trial:

```
'BEGIN{ SKIP=0; counter=0}
{ 
if ( $1=="MSG" && SKIP==0 )
{
    FS=" "
    printf("\n%s",$5)
    SKIP=1;
}
else if ( $1=="MSG" && SKIP==1 )
{   
    FS=" "
    printf(" %d",$6)
    SKIP=0;
}
else if ($1!="MSG" && counter <=1500) {
{
    FS="\t"
    printf(" %.2f",($4+$5)/2)
    counter++
}
}

}
```

Comment: I see 4 columns and do not know what a valid data point is?

Comment: $3 and $4 are the vertical and horizontal pupil diameters for the left eye. They are averaged to create one data point. The above data is only a sample.

Comment: Essentially, it will produce a file with the message code and the averaged pupil diameter for each line in a row. The rows are not of equal length, thus I need to truncate them so all three trials have 1500 averaged diameters.

Comment: I know a for loop will do it, but I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: 5 and 6 are horizontal and vertical pupil diameters for the right eye. I am only using left eye pupil size.

Comment: @JasonGeller - please post the expected output to go with your sample input. Obviously make it something like 5 data points instead of 1500. When we ask for information on your input, we're not looking for domain-specific info like "is the vertical and horizontal pupil diameters" we're looking for "the 3rd and 5th fields are the key values that uniquely identify a data point" or whatever the real information is that will let us help you simply transform your data without us having to get degrees in optometry in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm until now not sure about your needs, but this is maybe a start point:

```
$1=="MSG" {
    if ($5 ~ /[0-9]+/){
        counter=0
        }
    printf("\n%s",$5)
    }
($1!="MSG") && ($3!=0) && (counter <= 10) {
    printf("\n %.2f",($3+$4)/2)
    counter++
    }
```

Comment: I want to know how I can write a for loop that takes a subset of the averaged sizes. So, for example, I only want the output to include 20 data points instead of 35.

Comment: The above is just a small sample of the actual data. In the actual data set I have three trials, each with 1500+ observations. Could I include something like: counter <=1500 to truncate all trials down?

Comment: You can set `... && (counter <= 1500)`  Are all trials in the same data file?

Comment: Output is written to eg `103.dat`, `104.dat` and so on. Please see my edit.

Comment: I need all the trials within the same output.

Comment: Then you can make a normal output redirection: `awk -f prog.awk infile > outfile`. Edited the code.